# Delay in drawing

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list view with two text view and a image view and items I populate it with are 114 , I have created the list view with my custom adapter but the problem is that it takes a while like approx. 1 sec to 2 secs to load up and show the activity where I am displaying the list and whenever I open the activity it take time to show , so how can I minimize this delay time?

Here is my code:

```
public class ListViewFragment extends ListFragment {

int suraPicNum;
ArrayList<ListItem> imageArry = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
String[] names;

ImageTextListAdapter adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewtest, container, false);

    suraPicNum = R.drawable.j415;
    for (int x = 1; x <= 30; x++) {
        imageArry.add(new ListItem(suraPicNum, R.drawable.j414, "Juz " + x,
                String.valueOf(x)));
        suraPicNum++;
    }

    adapter = new ImageTextListAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.list_item_image_text, imageArry);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}
}
```

And activity class:

```
public class ListFragActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragactivity);

    }
```

Comment: you mean its taking time to laoding your data in listview?

Comment: @rajshree I think so that it is taking time on loading the data

Comment: ok..,for that you shold use lazy laodind..,its is the best solution for loading data smoothly in listview

Comment: Try to search for 'lazy image loading'

Answer (score 4):

use this...[Endless Adapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless)

it will help you...:)

Answer (score 0):

use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to load all the images and then attach them to adapter.